# Sublime 3: How to make TAB reindent current line or the selected region (if present)?

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text-3

TAB key by default just puts a tab, and only indents depending on several contexts, which I don’t understand quite well.

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "reindent", "context":
    [
        { "key": "setting.auto_indent", "operator": "equal", "operand": true },
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": true },
        { "key": "preceding_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true },
        { "key": "following_text", "operator": "regex_match", "operand": "^$", "match_all": true }
    ]
},
```

I wanted to make tab `reindent` by default, but stripping the context

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "reindent", "args": {"single_line": false} },
```

made sublime reindent the whole file at once. And I don’t want that, since I want to keep custom indentation for shell heredocs.

Comment: Why do you have added the `args` with `single_line` as `false`? You could just remove the args or set `single_line` to `true`.

Comment: If `single_line` is set to `true`, TAB indents after the line above – which may have wrong indentation, and not after the language rules.

Answer (score 0):

To make tab reindent the current line when there is a selection on all lines within the cursor, you just need to do:

```
{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "indent", "context":
    [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": false, "match_all": false }
    ]
},

{ "keys": ["tab"], "command": "insert_best_completion", "args": {"default": "\t", "exact": true}, "context":
    [
        { "key": "selection_empty", "operator": "equal", "operand": true, "match_all": false }
    ]
},
```

---

#### Structure of a Context

**key**:
Name of the context whose value you want to query.

**operator**:
Type of test to perform against key‘s value. Defaults to equal.

**operand**:
The result returned by key is tested against this value.

**match_all**:
Requires the test to succeed for all selections. Defaults to false.

http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#structure-of-a-context
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html#context-operands